# Can any body help me to implement Google map in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting the bellow error while running. I created the map-key also.

**ERROR MSG:**

```
12-06 13:07:02.230: E/AndroidRuntime(527): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527): java.lang.IllegalAccessError: cross-loader access from pre-verified class
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(Native Method)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClass(DexFile.java:193)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:203)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
12-06 13:07:02.249: E/AndroidRuntime(527):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of your xml layout file? You might be using `MapView` instead of `com.google.android.maps.Mapview`.

Comment: Thats not an Issue. if you take google avd then it not raise issue

Answer (score 0):

[**This is good Example of Map**](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

**And i think this is right a way to get key ::**

To get certificate fingerprint (MD5) follow the simple steps below:

You need to get the keystore file for getting the certificate fingerprint (MD5).
Your keystore file can be found at the following path
**"C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\Android"**

(Or)

**"C:\Documents and Settings\.android"**

Keystore file name is "debug.keystore" file.
Copy the "debug.keystore" file to some other folder (ex: - "D:\Androidkeystore\") (its user friendly to use).
Open command Prompt and go to the Java installed directory. ("C:\Program Files\Java\\bin")
Then type the below line (given in box) and press enter.

**keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "D:\AndroidKeystore\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android**

Here the MD5 certificate fingerprint is **"64:88:A2:FC:AA:9F:B1:B0:CA:E4:D0:24:A8:1E:77:FB"**

this is working actually........but im getting small error here

this is my path-`C:\ANDROID\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore"C:\ANDROID\debugkey\debug.keystore"-storepass android -keypass android`

keytool error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Usage error, android is not a legal c
ommand

and finally i have solve from here ::

[**For more ..**](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

as you got fingerprints copy it and past in Sign Up page. you got a **key successfully**

Answer (score 0):

Ifyour key is correct, it might be a missing `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in the manifest. You have to add this line in the application tag before defining the activitys.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you are using debug key not release key.